# Azure add user authentication method using Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm creating new user using GraphServiceClient with SignInType as userName something like this:

```
            var user = new User
        {
            AccountEnabled = true,

            GivenName = "Joe",
            Surname = "Bob",
            DisplayName = "Name",
            Mail = "joe@bob.com",
            MobilePhone = "111111111",
            Identities = new List<ObjectIdentity>()
            {
                new ObjectIdentity
                {
                    SignInType = "userName",
                    Issuer = "<Issuer...>",
                    IssuerAssignedId = "someName"
                },
            },
            PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false,
                Password = "<pass>"
            },
            PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword",
        };

        await gsc.Users.Request().AddAsync(user);
```

After that user is created in Azure and I can use this account for login into app that is using B2C SignIn policy. But when I want invoke ResetPassword policy for that user, after successfully email verification, I'm getting error: "An account could not be found for the provided user ID.". After some trial and error I've figure out that there is missing data in azure user profile tab "Authentication methods" When I fill out input for email everything is working fine and user is able to reset password.

So I'm searching for a way how to populate user email into this section "Authentication methods" during creation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this circumstance, where you want to create users via Graph API, you cannot populate the strongAuthenticationEmail attribute usng Graph API. This attribute holds the email associated with a username based account for password reset operations. User Flows will read this attribute during password reset. Therefore this wont work.

You need to use a custom policy for a username based journey and replace all instances of strongAuthenticationEmail with extension_whatever. Then in your Graph API payload, insert the email address in a key called extension_GUID_whatever.

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to populate this strongAuthenticationEmail by code? using Azure AD Graph API or something else?

Comment: Nope, hence my answer

Comment: hey, one more question, I'm not sure how to insert this extension from code I added one additional props like this:
:
        `AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                {
                    { "extension_1111111111111111111111111111111_customEmail", "test@test.com" },
                },`
But it's not working :( I don't see this value in custom policy

Comment: You added it as an output claim in a AAD technical profile that is doing a read op? You won’t see this claim in the portal.